# Why is integer(0) outputted when I use the which() function?

Tags: r

I am trying to determine which variables in my V1 column have values in the V5 column that are in the range of 95-105 and also have values in the V6 column that are in the 7-13 range. I am using the which function and attempting to store the names of the variables in V1 under the variable x but I keep getting the output integer(0) or character(0) and I'm not sure what that means. An image of my code is attached below.

[image]

Comment: According to your description, there's a typo in your `which` command - `df$V7 >= 13` should be `df$V6 >= 13`

Comment: looks like your first attempt copied-and-pasted a `>` at the beginning of the command, so it didn't execute at all.  Can you please cut-and-paste **text** rather than posting screenshots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`integer(0)` means there are **no** elements of your data frame that satisfy the conditions. (You could try

```
with(df, any(95 <= V5 & V5 <= 105 & 
             13 <= V6 & V6 <= 17))
```

(edited on the basis of @H1's comment, to match your description rather than your code); rearranging slightly to approximate the `A < B < C` syntax that R's parser can't handle ...)

You should probably check `str(df)` and/or `summary(df)` (or `sapply(df, class)`) to make sure that your data frame has really been read in as intended (or use `dplyr::read_csv()`, which prints information about the classes inferred from the data set. In particular, any typos in your data that make an entry *not* be a valid number (extra decimal point, missing value such as "?" not recognized as missing, etc.) will make R interpret the entire column as a character (since you've set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`) rather than a numeric variable.

If you want to force columns 2-14 to numeric, you can use `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.numeric)` however, it would be better practice to find and fix any problems upstream ...